# there is log echo and return echo in a function but it is returning only log echo only value instead of return cho

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

code :

```
function1(){

matchType=$1

if [[ $matchType == 'contains' ]];then
  PID=`pgrep -f  a`
elif [[ $matchType == 'exact' ]];then
  PID=`pgrep -x  a`
fi


if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
 echo "process id fetched successful"  // log echo
else
 echo"process id fetched failed"  // log echo
fi

echo "$PID"  //return echo

}


function2()
{
output=$(function1 contains)
}
```

value of **output** variable is 'process id fetched failed' instead of PID which I echoed at last in function 1

Requirement :  it should return PID value to function2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
function1(){

matchType=$1

if [[ $matchType == 'contains' ]];then
  PID=`pgrep -f  a`
elif [[ $matchType == 'exact' ]];then
  PID=`pgrep -x  a`
fi


if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
 echo "process id fetched successful" >&2 # this will set stdout fd to stderror
else
 echo"process id fetched failed" >&2  # this will set stdout fd to stderror
fi

echo "$PID"

}


function2()
{
output=$(function1 contains)
}
```

or where do you want to log?